# Prove that $(n-1)!S_m\geq (n-m)!m!P_m.$

Tags: inequality

> If $a_1, a_2,\cdots a_n$ be all positive rationals such that $S_n=a_1^m+a_2^m+\cdots +a_n^m$, $P_m=\sum a_1a_2\cdots a_m$  (the sum of products m taken m at a time). Prove that $$(n-1)!S_m\geq (n-m)!m!P_m.$$

Here one has to apply the laws of Inequalities.

$AM\geq GM$ on m number of terms given by $a_1^m, a_2^m, \cdots ,a_m^m$ one gets $$\frac{a_1^m+a_2^m+\cdots +a_m^m}{m}\geq \left(a_1^ma_2^m\cdots a_m^m\right)^{1/m}$$ 
i.e $$a_1^m+a_2^m+\cdots +a_m^m\geq m\left(a_1a_2\cdots a_m\right)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
Similarly, $$a_1^m+a_3^m+\cdots +a_{m+1}^{m}\geq m\left(a_1a_3\cdots a_{m+1}\right)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~(2)$$
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\cdots \cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$

There are $ \binom{n}{m}$ number of such inequalities. Adding we get, 
RHS Sum=$m\left(\left(a_1a_2\cdots a_m\right)+\left(a_1a_3\cdots a_{m+1}\right)\cdots \right)=m \sum a_1a_2\cdots a_m=mP_m$

But what about LHS Sum and how to complete the proof. Please help.

Comment: You are basically done! Count the number of times say $a_1^m$ appears in the left-hand side. (It sounds like a homework problem perhaps, so I will just give you that hint.)

Comment: @Malkoun how to count it, please

Comment: it corresponds to choosing $m-1$ objects out of $n-1$ objects.